# 'str' object is not callable - SuccessMessageMixin

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I get this error in a project whith SuccessMessageMixin and and not know why. This is my code in view.py.

```
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin
from django.views.generic import CreateView

class CampanaNueva(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = Campana
    template_name = "licencias_campana_nueva.html"
    fields = ['temporada', 'descripcion']
    success_message = "a"
```

And Raise this error on save:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/licencias/editar/1

Django Version: 1.9.4
Python Version: 3.4.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'bootstrap3',
 'home',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'socios',
 'equipaciones',
 'licencias']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'cc_corbelo.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in post
  279.         return super(BaseUpdateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in post
  222.             return self.form_valid(form)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\messages\views.py" in form_valid
  14.             messages.success(self.request, success_message)

Exception Type: TypeError at /licencias/editar/1
Exception Value: 'str' object is not callable
```

I have this function working in another project without problems...

Comment: Error is about `TypeError at /licencias/editar/1` but you are showing us `CampanaNueva` are you sure that problem in this view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got exactly this same message when I accidentally used the `messages` framework incorrectly in the `form_valid` method of a completely different view in my project.

The correct code should have been:

`messages.success(request, "Deactivated product")`

But what I had written instead was

`messages.success = "Deactivated product"`

This code doesn't work, but it doesn't cause an error on the page, either! However, as soon as I submitted a *different* form that used the `SuccessMessageMixin`, I would see the `'str' object is not callable` error.

(Having a problem on one page cause an error on a completely different page was fun to debug.)